# Download software for windows or mac, or Windows or Mac?

Tags: bug, election, capitalization

> [image]

After an election ends ([example](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/6)), there's a banner offering readers to download a software to audit the results. However, the names of the two platforms, windows and mac, aren't correctly capitalized as they should, since they're Proper Nouns and should Be Capitalized As Such.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improve election results message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348493/improve-election-results-message)