# Improve election results message

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, wording, capitalization

When [an election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/4) is finished, the following message is shown:

> The results of this election can be [viewed online via OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/results/5983115128340480).[Download the election data](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/4) and use OpenSTV for [windows](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/download-openstv?os=pc) or [mac](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/download-openstv?os=mac) to audit the results.

Can we:

1. separate both sentences with a space
2. properly capitalize [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)
3. either properly capitalize [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) or change it to [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)?

Comment: Oh hey, the download route errors out too for good measure. Judging by the exception in the logs, something probably changed with how .NET core works vs the full framework. Leaving this comment as a mental note for fixing later.

Comment: This is a bit broader but was requested once before: [Download software for windows or mac, or Windows or Mac?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324218/download-software-for-windows-or-mac-or-windows-or-mac) The person who adds the OpaVote link probably put the space in previously. :D

Comment: @AdamLear Here's the relevant meta bug report for that server error: [Server error when downloading OpenSTV software using link on election pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347871/server-error-when-downloading-openstv-software-using-link-on-election-pages)

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Thanks!

Comment: Also, the Mac build is 32-bit and therefore doesn't work on recent versions of macOS. I guess that's probably not easy to fix since OpenSTV appears to be discontinued.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The missing space was probably a .Net Framework to .Net Core regression.  I went with "macOS" for item 3 because that's where my heart guided me.

Comment: You have a good heart.

Comment: Follow your heart!

Comment: Trust your feelings!